# Wordpress custom page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make new custom page in wordpress where I can communicate with database and show results. I added one in root folder. It appears; but when I try to display menu, headers. It gives error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()
```

Comment: Why you don't say? An error, really?

Comment: question updated. How can I add page? Please....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Template Name: (some name)` comment on top of script, and when you add new page in admin, select your new template.
Also, this PHP script needs to be in `/wp-content/themes/(theme-name)/` folder.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Here:

[image]

Comment: Where can I open this image you attached.

Comment: @imi http://yourwordpress.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page , on the right side... http://pokit.org/get/1a690840a3d255f432d9f9c774279bdd.png

Comment: There is no template drop down in my wordpress admin.

Comment: @imi All Pages --> Add New (bottom right) OR if page exists: All Pages --> Quick Edit (right)